# Custom ADO.NET implementation as a client for a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, ado.net, odbc

We use a particular ODBC driver here to access a legacy database. Our homemade software (a 2 tier [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) [winform](/questions/tagged/winform) application that connects to an [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) database) could really use it for some operations. Unfortunately, due to licencing restrictions we cannot deploy the ODBC driver on more than one computer. I'm looking for a way to go around that.

My initial thought was a WCF service and POCOs. However, since the app references a library with a rich set of generic ADO.NET helper functions, I really want to reuse these to communicate with the server. So I'm thinking of making my own ADO.NET implementation to access the WCF service that will, in turn, expose session objects to process queries sent by the client.

Anybody did something like this before? What challenges awaits with implementing my own ADO provider? Also, is there something like this that already exists, before I go and reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ODBC-ODBC Bridge to access you legacy ODBC driver from any other machine and still access it via ODBC. Sounds to me like this would be a lot less effort.

Update: I can only describe the Easysoft ODBC-ODBC Bridge as I've not seen the code of any other bridge. At the client end you install the OOB client ODBC driver. On the server end you install a service. The client end effectively sends your ODBC calls and data to the server where they are redirected to the actual ODBC driver you want to use. Of course, there are loads of optimisations performed both in the ODBC APIs and the protocol. There are a lot of advantages to this a) you can use a driver you cannot get for the platform you want to code on b) you can use a 32 bit application to talk to a 64 bit driver or vice versa c) you might only be able to or want to use one license for the driver/database on the server d) you can cross networks to access a remote driver etc.

Transactions are handled properly in the Easysoft OOB.

Comment: How does it work, exactly? It has it's own ODBC driver? And it passes the queries as-is to the true ODBC on the server? How about transaction support?